# How to center the div horizontally elements having container and row class in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

The section cannot align properly in the center and neither does the div have a container class. If there is any bootstrap class for alignment or do I have to create CSS code for aligning the items in the div tag.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<section class="bg-secondary bg-gradient p-5 text-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="text-center">Contact Us</h1>
                <br>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-light">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label" for="place">Place</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="place" type="text" placeholder="Place" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label" for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="emailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label" for="mobNumber">Mobile Number</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="mobNumber" type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label" for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" type="text" placeholder="Type your Message here..." style="height: 10rem;"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                      <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?
I have assigned a **col-md-6**  to cover all the elements under the **row** and I converted **col-md-6** in the **form-group** classes to **col-12**.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<section class="bg-secondary bg-gradient p-5 text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="text-center">Contact Us</h1>
      <br>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-light">
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label class="form-label" for="place">Place</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="place" type="text" placeholder="Place" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label class="form-label" for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="emailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label class="form-label" for="mobNumber">Mobile Number</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="mobNumber" type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label class="form-label" for="message">Message</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="message" type="text" placeholder="Type your Message here..." style="height: 10rem;"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```